# Chrome speech API network error

Tags: google-chrome, voice-recognition, webspeech-api

I'm trying to create a PHP web application using Chrome web speech API. I'm always getting network errors. But, I have a good network connection.

```
window.SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition 
                               || window.webkitSpeechRecognition || null;
    if (window.SpeechRecognition === null) {
    } else {
        var recognizer = new window.SpeechRecognition();
        recognizer.continuous = false;
        recognizer.lang = 'en-US';
        recognizer.onstart = function() {
            recognizing = true;
        };
        recognizer.onresult = function(event) {
        };
    }
recognizer.onerror = function(event) { 
            alert(event.error);
            ignore_onend = true;
            if (event.error == 'not-allowed') {
                alert("Allow to access your microphone");
            }
            recognizer.stop();
            recognizer.start();
};
```

Thanks

Comment: Please include your source code in the question.  Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This appears to be of-topic.  It either is asking for debugging help without including enough information to debug, or it is about general networking issues.

Comment: @Makyen I'm using above code. Please help

Comment: Please provide the exact error-text from the errors which you are experiencing.

Comment: @markyen It just returns "network" from event.error

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem since the last Google update and I am sure that there is a bug in the last Update. I have similar thread at RecognizerIntent gives error after latest Google Search update
My android app gives network error for recognizerintent. Till then, there was no network problem.
In summary the error is W/JavaNetConnection﹕ Failed to get connection status. java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://www.google.com/m/voice-search/down?pair=6239918a-dc45-4eea-ac6f-b9bf8de57ced